# Set number of parity drives to 0 in Minio reduced redundancy storage class

Tags: minio

For our storage with non-critical data we don't need any replication at all, therefore we do not need parity drives. But it seems that making number of parity drives in Minio less then 2 is not allowed. Is it possible to set it to 0 somehow?

Answer (score 0):

@Datacult, it is not possible to set the parity to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable parity now, see https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-server/settings/storage-class.html

Set env MINIO_STORAGE_CLASS_STANDARD to EC:0 means:
The minimum supported value is 0, which indicates no erasure coding protections. These deployments rely entirely on the storage controller or resource for availability / resiliency.